# TensorFlow: how to restore T-GCN cell based trained model weights and biases?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, transfer-learning

I trained a model on a specific dataset and saved it as a meta, I want to restore the model and use its weights and biases on another dataset the code isn't mine but I'm trying to restore the architecture after it was saved to metafile, the TGCN was designed by the lehaifeng to predict speeds on edges of a graph.
You can find the source code belongs to [lehaifeng](https://github.com/lehaifeng) and his teammates through the following link:

https://github.com/lehaifeng/T-GCN

I tried many workarounds and ran into numerous errors I can't post all of them here, is it possible to do transfer learning using the model I post above because I can't use this architecture on a new dataset

I have tried using to `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL/TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)` to set the global variable to the restored model global variables and then pass it to the optimizer it's telling me there are no variables in the restored graph.

one other problem is the model can't iterate over a tensor unless I'm using eager execution and that I have to use tf.map_fn, you can't use eager execution when calling placeholders from the trained model as tensor using `graph.get_tensor_by_name()`

```
import pickle as pkl
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import os
import numpy.linalg as la
from input_data import preprocess_data,load_doha_data,load_los_data
from tgcn import tgcnCell
###from gru import GRUCell 

from visualization import plot_result,plot_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error,mean_absolute_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

time_start = time.time()
####Settings####
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 0.003, 'Initial learning rate.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('training_epoch', 10, 'Number of epochs to train.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('gru_units', 100, 'hidden units of gru.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('seq_len',4  , '  time length of inputs.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('pre_len', 1, 'time length of prediction.')
flags.DEFINE_float('train_rate', 0.8, 'rate of training set.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 64, 'batch size.')
flags.DEFINE_string('dataset', 'los', 'doha or los.')
flags.DEFINE_string('model_name', 'tgcn', 'tgcn')
model_name = FLAGS.model_name
data_name = FLAGS.dataset
train_rate =  FLAGS.train_rate
seq_len = FLAGS.seq_len
output_dim = pre_len = FLAGS.pre_len
batch_size = FLAGS.batch_size
lr = FLAGS.learning_rate
training_epoch = FLAGS.training_epoch
gru_units = FLAGS.gru_units

###### load data ######
if data_name == 'los':
data, adj = load_los_data('los')

time_len = data.shape[0]
print(time_len)
num_nodes = data.shape[1]
print(num_nodes)
data1 =np.mat(data,dtype=np.float32)

#### normalization
max_value = np.max(data1)
data1  = data1/max_value
trainX, trainY, testX, testY = preprocess_data(data1, time_len, train_rate, seq_len, pre_len)

totalbatch = int(trainX.shape[0]/batch_size)
training_data_count = len(trainX)

def TGCN(_X, _weights, _biases):
###
cell_1 = tgcnCell(gru_units, adj, num_nodes=num_nodes)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell_1], state_is_tuple=True)
_X = tf.unstack(_X, axis=1)
outputs, states = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell, _X, dtype=tf.float32)
m = []
for i in outputs:
    o = tf.reshape(i,shape=[-1,num_nodes,gru_units])
    o = tf.reshape(o,shape=[-1,gru_units])
    m.append(o)
last_output = m[-1]
output = tf.matmul(last_output, _weights['out2']) + _biases['out2']
output = tf.reshape(output,shape=[-1,num_nodes,pre_len])
output = tf.transpose(output, perm=[0,2,1])
output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[-1,num_nodes])
return output, m, states

###### placeholders ######
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, seq_len, num_nodes],name="inputs1")
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, pre_len, num_nodes],name="lables1")

# Graph weights 
weights = {
'out2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([gru_units, pre_len], mean=1.0), name='weight_o')}
biases = {
'out2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([pre_len]),name='bias_o')}

if model_name == 'tgcn':
pred,ttts,ttto = TGCN(inputs, weights, biases)

y_pred = pred


###### optimizer ######
lambda_loss = 0.0010
Lreg = lambda_loss * sum(tf.nn.l2_loss(tf_var) for tf_var in tf.trainable_variables())
label = tf.reshape(labels, [-1,num_nodes])
##loss
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.l2_loss(y_pred-label) + Lreg)
##rmse
error = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_pred-label)))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)

###### Initialize session ######
variables = tf.global_variables()

#Create a saver object which will save all the variables
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
sess.run(init)


out = 'out2/%s'%(model_name)
#out = 'out/%s_%s'%(model_name,'perturbation')
path1 = '%s_%s_lr%r_batch%r_unit%r_seq%r_pre%r_epoch%r'%(model_name,data_name,lr,batch_size,gru_units,seq_len,pre_len,training_epoch)
path = os.path.join(out,path1)
if not os.path.exists(path):
os.makedirs(path)

###### evaluation ######
def evaluation(a,b):
rmse = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(a,b))
mae = mean_absolute_error(a, b)
F_norm = la.norm(a-b,'fro')/la.norm(a,'fro')
r2 = 1-((a-b)**2).sum()/((a-a.mean())**2).sum()
var = 1-(np.var(a-b))/np.var(a)
return rmse, mae, 1-F_norm, r2, var


x_axe,batch_loss,batch_rmse,batch_pred = [], [], [], []
test_loss,test_rmse,test_mae,test_acc,test_r2,test_var,test_pred = [],[],[],[],[],[],[]

for epoch in range(training_epoch):
for m in range(totalbatch):
    mini_batch = trainX[m * batch_size : (m+1) * batch_size]
    mini_label = trainY[m * batch_size : (m+1) * batch_size]
    _, loss1, rmse1, train_output = sess.run([optimizer, loss, error, y_pred],
                                             feed_dict = {inputs:mini_batch, labels:mini_label})
    batch_loss.append(loss1)
    batch_rmse.append(rmse1 * max_value)

 # Test completely at every epoch
 loss2, rmse2, test_output = sess.run([loss, error, y_pred],
                                     feed_dict = {inputs:testX, labels:testY})
test_label = np.reshape(testY,[-1,num_nodes])
rmse, mae, acc, r2_score, var_score = evaluation(test_label, test_output)
test_label1 = test_label * max_value
test_output1 = test_output * max_value
test_loss.append(loss2)
test_rmse.append(rmse * max_value)
test_mae.append(mae * max_value)
test_acc.append(acc)
test_r2.append(r2_score)
test_var.append(var_score)
test_pred.append(test_output1)

print('Iter:{}'.format(epoch),
      'train_rmse:{:.4}'.format(batch_rmse[-1]),
     'test_loss:{:.4}'.format(loss2),
    'test_rmse:{:.4}'.format(rmse),
     'test_acc:{:.4}'.format(acc))

saver.save(sess, './TGCNpretrain.model')
print (tf.contrib.framework.list_variables('./TGCNpretrain.model'))
time_end = time.time()
print(time_end-time_start,'s')
```

So to sum up my problem, how do I restore and load this model on another data set.
You can download all other code callback functions and data sets from the source code link make sure you change paths so that the main.py can import its input matrices. thanks in advance

p.s I'm an extreme beginner to Tesnorflow in particular and a beginner in Python in general. so pardon my inexperience in expressing the problem.